# How to use v-text-area rules option?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to set rules to control buttons that are inside of v-text-area on Vue2/Vuetify. How can I do this?
I tried several things, please do not judge me i am beginner of coding concept

Comment: please share some code

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Vuetify validation rules, you need to wrap all elements on which you want to perform validation in a `<v-form>` element.

On your input components, you need to provide an array to the `rules` prop with the names of functions you define which perform validation.

The functions which validate take the value as an input and return `true` if the input is valid and `false` or a failure string if the input is invalid.

An example of such a function defined in the `methods` section would be:

```js
isNumber(input) {
  return /[0-9]+/g.test(input) || "input must be a number";
}
```

Passing it to your `v-text-area` would look like  this:

```html
  <v-text-area :rules="[isNumber]" />
```

More info is available in the [#rules](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#rules) section of Vueitfy's Form docs.